# VariantView for TYPO3 8.7

Tags: php, typo3

There has been a solution for template variants, which allowed to set a suffix for a fluid template file used by an extbase controller. It was created by [Peter Niederlag](https://gist.github.com/pniederlag/822613) and was improved by [Bastian Waidelich](https://gist.github.com/bwaidelich/988628/e0a247f2d91905809d678a83bd5b578a025de80c).

The solution is not working any longer in TYPO3 8.7 because the code has been refactored and the method `expandGenericPathPattern` in `TemplateView` does not exist anymore.

How should I implement such variant view in TYPO3 8.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following classes in my extension, which implement the VariantView for TYPO3 8.7.

Classes\View\VariantView.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extkey\View;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\TemplateView;

/**
 * Extended Fluid Template View that supports different "variants"
 *
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3 or later
 */
class VariantView extends TemplateView
{
    /**
     * @param string $layoutVariant
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLayoutVariant($layoutVariant)
    {
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $this->baseRenderingContext->setTemplatePaths($objectManager->get(TemplatePaths::class));
        /** @var TemplatePaths $templatePaths */
        $templatePaths = $this->baseRenderingContext->getTemplatePaths();
        $templatePaths->setLayoutVariant($layoutVariant);
    }

    const DEFAULT_LAYOUT_VARIANT = '.default';
}
```

Classes\View\TemplatePaths.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extkey\View;

class TemplatePaths extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\TemplatePaths
{
    /**
     * Layout variant to use for this view.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $layoutVariant = VariantView::DEFAULT_LAYOUT_VARIANT;

    /**
     * @param string $layoutVariant
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLayoutVariant($layoutVariant)
    {
        $this->layoutVariant = $layoutVariant;
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for parent class method which adds layout variant in action parameter
     *
     * @param string $controller
     * @param string $action
     * @param string $format
     * @return string|NULL
     * @api
     */
    public function resolveTemplateFileForControllerAndActionAndFormat($controller, $action, $format = self::DEFAULT_FORMAT)
    {
        $action = $action . $this->layoutVariant;
        return parent::resolveTemplateFileForControllerAndActionAndFormat($controller, $action, $format = self::DEFAULT_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

In your controller add the following lines:

```
 protected function setViewConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\ViewInterface $view) {
   parent::setViewConfiguration($view);
   $view->setLayoutVariant($this->settings['layoutVariant']);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->view->getRenderingContext()->setControllerAction('MyAction.Variant');` should do the trick (from any initializeAction method or within action method). Note that contrary to the view override class you linked to, this approach means you *must have the original action template in the path*.

Comment: The class ```ViewInterface``` does not contain a method called ```getRenderingContext```. ```$this->view``` is defined as ```ViewInterface```, so what do I have to change to make ```$this->view->getRenderingContext()``` work?

Comment: You use the normal TemplateView instead.

Comment: I had a closer look again. `protected $defaultViewObjectName` had to be set to `\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\TemplateView::class`.
What I do not like on this solution is the requirement to have to original action template in path which leads to a lot of unnecessary files laying around.